# Android Target Change

Tags: android, eclipse

I have the following in my Manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />`
```

and the following in my project.properties file:

```
target=android-15
```

When I right click on project -> proprties -> android -> android 17

My manifest didn't change, but my project.properties changed as

```
target=android-17
```

And I have my emulator that is set for API level 19, so my app runs perfectly.

My question is:

1. What is the difference between the two target set ups in project.properties and android manifest?
2. Which one is considerd while running apk? do the two need to be same or what?
3. In android manifest and project.properties I have given the target as less than 17 but it still runs on emulator for version 19? So what's the point in giving 17 in apk files?

Comment: You should modify Android Manifest yourself. project.properties isn't considered at runtime.

Comment: so then whats the need the need of project.properties file? If its of no use we can remove it while running?

Comment: and one more thing when i am chnging by right clicking change is made in project.properties not in manifest. why so means if we changing by right clicking it is used by project.proprties while building purpose. Am i correct?

Comment: It is generated and used by android build tools :)

Comment: So it means that we can build with any version that is decided by properties file and can then run with any version that is decided by manifest? Or is there any limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two points have been answered by fremmedehenvendelser.

3 - the targetSdkVersion doesn't mean that higher versions of the OS can't run older code. Higher versions of the OS are down-compatible. You only specify that you are not using the newest features offered by the newest OSes.

Comment: can u please tell me whats the use of proguard-project.txt file in explorer ?

Comment: It's used by the ProGuard tool for obfuscating your app before the release to the public, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11025655/2649012)